# Better way of handling xib button press than chained delegates?

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented some code including protocols to chain the active instance up to the VC to allow for Segues and am wondering if there's a better way to solve this problem or if I'm handling the Segue the wrong way.

Segues within child classes do not work because they are not in the primary VC

Excerpt from VC file

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, TableViewControllerDelegate  {


    func didButtonPressed() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "destStory", sender: self)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableViewController.delegate = self
    }




}
```

```swift
protocol TableViewControllerDelegate {
    func didButtonPressed()
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, TableViewCellDelegate {
    func didButtonPressed() {
        delegate?.didButtonPressed()
    }

    let test = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
    var instanceOf = self
    var delegate: TableViewControllerDelegate?
```

Excerpt from cell file

```swift
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func didButtonPressed()
}
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!


    @IBAction func buttonOnePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.didButtonPressed()
    }
```

This functions the way I'd expect but seems potentially confusing to work with.

Comment: What is confusing? Be more specific... If it works, what is the problem?

Comment: By the way, your delegates must be `class` delegates and they have to be declared `weak`, otherwise you are creating strong-reference cycles and memory leaks.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for that, what do you mean by "class delegate" I think I understand declaring them as weak e.g "weak var delegate" instead.

Comment: @illuzian `protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class`. That means they can be implemented only by classes (not structs). If you don't make them `class`, you won't be able to use `weak`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using *closures* instead of delegate.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var buttonPressedClosure: (() -> Void))?
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!


    @IBAction func buttonOnePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonPressedClosure?()
    }
}
```

Also, you can add target action for cell's button inside *cellForRow* **UITableViewDelegate** function directly, but it is a dirty way in my opinion.

```
let cell = ...
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Adding targets or even accessing cell subviews from data source delegate is not a good idea.